# Discrepancy in JSON ObjectMapper readValue parsing - gives Null sometimes

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am facing a bizarre situation while parsing a json string  using readValue() of ObjectMaper. I am using Jackson 2.4.1 along with Spring 4.0.6. 
Problem is, same json string when fed to readValue() gives null at times and other times valid object. 
**JSON String** :

```
{"productGroupInfoTransport":    {"groupId":36,"range":"LMEURSMA","productType":"LMFE","status":"ANNOUNCE","regionsList":[],"productsList":[],"groupName":"Bright Start test"}}
```

Code:

```
public Object getData(String jSONObject, String action, String module)
        throws Exception {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,
            false); 
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES,
            false); 
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT,
            false); 
    //mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.   WRITE_NULL_PROPERTIES, false);
    String transport = null;

    if (jSONObject.contains(ERROR)) {

        transport = "Exception";

        throw new Exception("Unable to read Data");
    } else {

        transport = getTransport(action, module);
    }

    Object transportObject = null;

    transportObject = mapper.readValue(jSONObject, getTransport(transport));

    return transportObject;

}
```

ProductTransport :

```
package com.leggmason.lmEPAM.transport;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.leggmason.lmEPAM.model.ProductGroupModel;

public class ProductGroupTransport extends EPAMTransport<ProductGroupModel> {

@JsonProperty("productGroupInfoTransport")
protected ProductGroupModel modelObject;

@JsonProperty("productGroupTransport")
protected List<ProductGroupModel> data;

@JsonProperty("productGroupTransport")
@Override
public List<ProductGroupModel> getListData() {
    return this.data;
}

@JsonProperty("productGroupTransport")
@Override
public void setData(List<ProductGroupModel> data) {
    this.data = (List<ProductGroupModel>) data;

}

@Override
public String getModule() {

    return null;
}

@JsonProperty("productGroupInfoTransport")
@Override
public ProductGroupModel getObject() {
    return this.modelObject;
}

@JsonProperty("productGroupInfoTransport")
public void setObject(ProductGroupModel modelObject) {
    this.modelObject = modelObject;

}

@Override
public void setObject(Object modelObject) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

In above code when JsonString is passed, one time ProductTransposrt will have its modelObject populated correctly with Object but as I restart the server, same JSON string will give modelObject as null after parsing. I fail to understand why. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code for parsing json object

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jSONObject);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("productGroupInfoTransport");
System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(0).getString("groupId"))
```

Now you can parse json string properly.
It may be help for only parsing json string.